# SAS web scrape of HIBOR rate

Tags: sas

I tried to scrape daily HIBOR rate using SAS

```
filename hibor url "http://www.hkab.org.hk";

data test;
    infile hibor length=len lrecl=32767;
    input line $varying32767. len;
run;
```

While it gave ERROR:

```
NOTE: Unable to connect to host www.hkab.org.hk. Check validity of host name.
ERROR: Host name www.hkab.org.hk not found.
```

Comment: try using filename hibor 'www.hkab.org.hk'; instead

Comment: the specific address is not available... error pop up

Comment: Your code seems to work fine on my box, with IP address as 205.255.224.10. Make sure your Ping come through first.

Comment: Try adding :80 to the URL.  We had SAS installations where that was required to get HTTP access to work, even though 80 is the default port for HTTP. "http://www.hkab.org.hk:80"

Comment: i able to access the website using browser. Is there anything wrong for the setting of SAS?

Comment: Is SAS installed on your local machine or are you running SAS via a SAS Server?

Comment: SAS is installed on my local machine.

Comment: Do you use explicit proxy? If so, you have to specify it in your filename. Also, have a look at PROC HTTP, this method is more robust when it comes to web scraping.